# Oracle: Using Pseudo column value in the same Select statement

Tags: oracle, select

I have a scenario in oracle where i need to be able to reuse the value of a pseudo column which was calculated previously within the same select statement something like:

```
select 'output1' process, process || '-Output2' from Table1
```

I don't want to the repeat the first columns logic again in the second column for maintenance purposes, currently it is done as

```
select 'output1' process, 'output1' || '-Output2' name from Table1
```

since i have 4 such columns which depend on the previous column output, repeating would be a maintenance nightmare

Edit: i included table name and removed dual, so that no assumptions are made about that this is not a complex process, my actual statement does have 2 to 3 joins on different tables

Comment: Unfortunately you can't re-use calculated columns in the same scope. It might seem a bit overkill but factored sub-queries or inline views such as Adam Paynter suggests will force the calculation to occur at a different level meaning you can re-use the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could calculate the value in a sub-query:

```
select calculated_output process, calculated_output || '-Output2' name from
(
    select 'output1' calculated_output from dual
)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the subquery factoring syntax - i think it is more readable myself:

```
with tmp as
(  
  select 'output' process from dual
)
select 
  process, process || '-Output2' from tmp;
```

Comment: I tend to forget that the `WITH` syntax actually exists. :)

Comment: The only possible downside is that (depending on the Oracle version) the WITH query will be executed as a view - with possible performance issues (of course, this is sometimes an advantage).

Answer (score 2):

very similar to the previous poster, but I prefer the method I show below, it is more readable, thusly more supportable, in my opinion

```
select val1 || val2 || val3 as val4, val1 from (
   select 'output1' as val1, '-output2' as val2, '-output3' as val3 from dual
)
```